# Docker server networking - reject incoming connections but allow outgoing

Tags: docker, nginx, networking, reverse-proxy, iptables

We use Docker containers to deploy multiple small applications on our servers that are reachable on the public internet.  Some of the services need to communicate to each other, but are deployed on different servers, due to different hardware requirements (the servers are on different network and different IP).

**Q:** What would be the best way to configure blocking of incoming requests to SERVER:PORT except for some allowed IPs and at the same time allow all outgoing connections of the Docker containers?

Two major things we played with and tried out to get them working:

1. Bound Docker port mappings to 127.0.0.1 and route every traffic through an nginx. This is really config heavy and some infrastructure components aren't possible to proxy via http(s), so we need to add them to nginx.conf stream-server block and therefore open a port on the server (that is accessible by everyone).
2. Use iptables to restrict access to the published ports. So something like this: `iptables -A INPUT -I DOCKER-USER -p tcp -i eth0 -j DROP`. But this also have 2 major downfalls. First it seems that it's quite hard to allow multiple IP adresses in such a construct and on the other hand this approach seems to block our docker outgoing connections (to the internet) as well. E. g.: After we activated it a `ping google.com` from within a docker container was rejected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I get this. In term of design, what is available to the external world is in a DMZ or published through an API gateway.

Your docker swarm/kubernetes cluster shall not be accessible directly through the internet or only the API gateway or the application on the DMZ.

So quite likely your docker server shall not be accessible directly. And even if that is the case, if you don't explicitely export a port to the host/outside of the cluster, it stay restricted to the virtuals networks of docker to allow cross container communication.

Comment: Thought a while about that and you're totally right! Thank you for getting me on the right track, I wanted to solve something that shouldn't be solved that way.

In addition to the DMZ approach: Is there some recommended way of blocking all incoming network requests for docker and other services that I should be aware of? I'll migrate all existing services to the local bound and restrict them therefore of external access, but there will be some services that can't be migrated for now, cause I don't own them.

Comment: My understand is that for production, you don't use docker alone but at least docker swarn (easy if you know docker & docker-compose) or kubernetes (the industry standard) on top of docker. Theses technologies allow to easily define cluster of containers (good at least for stability and redundancy) with automatic load balencing and strategy for canary & rollout deployements. Inside these cluster, you can define the rule you want. By default all port are closed even between different services on the same cluster. Only what you open is accessible.

Comment: To protect from the internet you need an extra firewall, and have your DMZ or API grateway authenticating connection and letting only what is allowed to the cluster and for internal communitation within the cluster, you can strictly it to what you allow explictely.

Comment: And finally with this sttategy you can easily apply gitops. Change in production are a set of config files (docker swarm or kubernetes) describing the topology of your cluster (how many instance of each container, the version of imagges etc) inside a gfit repo. You can set it so that each time you make merge a PR (with peer review etc) then the lchange are applied automatically by the cluster without any downtime and without any human intervention  (Description of that strategy here: https://www.weave.works/technologies/gitops/).

Comment: Thx for your input! I'll adapt the process to that, gitops seems that it's a really good fit.